# PNGs are not transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, png, transparent

I've got a couple of PNGs with white set to transparent. In the XAML designer they're transparent:

[image]

But they're not transparent when the code is executed. I swap between two images & backgrounds on a button press. My code for swapping images:

```
   private void SwitchStyleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsVictorian = !IsVictorian;

        if (!IsVictorian)
        {

            ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
            ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\Cropped Aluminum.png", UriKind.Relative));
            MainCanvas.Background = ib;

            Left_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\GSBP Left Panel Modern.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        else {
            ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
            ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\Cropped Old Paper.png", UriKind.Relative));
            MainCanvas.Background = ib;
            Left_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\GSBP Left Panel Victorian.png", UriKind.Absolute));

        }
    }
```

I should point out that it's the Left_Image.Source that I want transparent; not the canvas background.

As per request, here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="General_Staff_BP.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:General_Staff_BP"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="General Staff Black Powder" Height="870" Width="1440" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Canvas x:Name= "MainCanvas">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Cropped Old Paper.png" Stretch="None"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Grid Height="870" Width="1440" 
          HorizontalAlignment ="Left" VerticalAlignment ="Top" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" ></Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Button x:Name="SwitchStyleButton"   Content="Change Style to Modern"  Click="SwitchStyleButton_Click" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Label>
        <Image x:Name="Left_Image" Source="Images\GSBP Left Panel Victorian.png" Stretch="None" />

    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

And screen shots:
[image]

And after button click:
[image]

As you can see, white isn't transparent.

And, I'm pretty sure that the images have white set to transparent:
[image]

Comment: could you display the wpf corresponding?

Comment: XAML added. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Could you show a figure of the executed program?

Comment: i dont see problem are you sure your image has transparency ?  the xaml is not a proof. could you test in gimp or other soft? or post your original image please i check it

Comment: I have a free open source project that might help you called Transparency Maker if you are interested.

https://github.com/DataJuggler/TransparencyMaker

I just posted a new video this morning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kfNKyr_oqg&list=PLKrW5tXCPiX2PxrLPszDzlcEZwQG-Qb8r

Comment: @Data juggler  great and interesting tool, thanks for sharingl!!

Comment: @Frenchy thanks! That is one of my favorite projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code is help you, here I just set Backgroung as transparent.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
```